# Dynamically add new element and change its content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I want to *"copy"* a certain elements and the change some of the text inside them with a *regex*.

So far so good: (/w working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/8ohzayyt/25/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var divs = $('div');
    var patt = /^\d\./;
    var match = null;
    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        match = ($(divs[i]).text().match(patt));
        $(divs[i]).text($(divs[i]).text().replace(match[0], "5."));
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div>1. peppers</div>
<div>2. eggs</div>
<div>3. pizza</div>
```

This works exactly the way I want it, but I want to add some of the content dynamically, but when I try to change the content of the copied `divs`, nothing happens.

Please refer to this fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/8ohzayyt/24/

I have put some comments, to be more clear what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thing that your problem is that you're not passing an element to your `changeLabel` function, but just a string.

Look at this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/8ohzayyt/26/

Here is the line I changed to make your code work:

```
var newContent = $("<hr/><div id='destination'>" + $("#holder").html() + "</div>");
```

I just wrapped your HTML in `$()`. this creates an element from the string.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
var newContent = $("<hr/><div id='destination'>" + $("#holder").html() + "</div>");
```

**EDIT:**
Brief explanation What I've done.

In order to make `$(el).find('div');` work `changeLabel()` needs an element. Instead of passing `newContent` as a string doing the above will make it pass as an element which will make `$(el).find('div');` work.

Comment: Why should the OP try this? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: In order to make `$(el).find('div');` work `changeLabel()` needs an element.

Comment: Edit your post and add the explanation @Fergoso